# Docker port forwarding cannot see the output on browser

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-14.04, dockerfile

I am a newbie to Docker. I'm using ubuntu 14.04 as my OS and I've installed Docker Community Edition by following instructions from https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#set-up-the-repository

I have a created a docker file for my project and run it using docker-compose file.
My Dockerfile is as follows.

```
# ImageName
FROM node:8.8.1

# Create app required directories
ENV appDir /usr/src/app
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app /usr/src/app/datas /usr/log/supervisor

# Change working directory
WORKDIR ${appDir}

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install vim\
    supervisor \
    python3 \
        python3-pip \
        python3-setuptools \
        groff \
        less \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip \
    && apt-get clean

RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install --upgrade awscli

# Install app dependencies
COPY graphql/package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g webpack

# Copy app source code
COPY graphql/ /usr/src/app
COPY datas/ /usr/src/app/datas

# Set Environment Variables
RUN echo export DATA_DIR=/usr/src/app/datas/ >> ~/.data_variables  && \
  echo "source ~/.data_variables" >> ~/.bash_login  && \
    echo "source ~/.data_variables" >> ~/.bashrc 

COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supercvisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

# Expose API port to the outside
EXPOSE 5000

# Launch application
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supercvisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf"]
```

My docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    image: graphql_img
    container_name: graphql_img_master
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

My supervisord.conf file

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:babelWatch]
command=npm run babelWatch

[program:monitor]
command=npm run monitor
```

As you can see I've exposed the port 5000, but when I try to check the output on the browser using the command `localhost:5000/graphql` it shows an error

> This site can’t be reached

I even tried to check for the ip address of docker container using "docker inspect" command and I've used that container ip address with the port still I'm getting the error. Can somebody please help me out on this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Additionally, it would also really helpful to know how to make the program "run monitor" to run on foreground using supervisor

Comment: what do you see when you run `docker ps` ?

Comment: wait what, why is port 5010 pointing to 5000? maybe there is your problem

Comment: Can you tell me what should I do in that case?

Comment: @Edwin Here is my output 
docker ps 
CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES 
db3723a242c0 graphql_img "/usr/bin/supervisor…" 2 hours ago Up 2 hours 0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp graphql_img_master

Comment: you can enter on the container and see if there all the things are running as supose to `docker exec -ti graphql_img_master /bin/bash`

Comment: Ya just checked by entering the container and everything is working as expected. But still I'm not able to see the output on the browser.